# Take all user entered data from one jsp page to another JSP page and after user confirmation submit it from the first jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

Here scenario is : user will enter the data in my main jsp page.When user hit on submit button i want to show all the data to user in another jsp page and want to take confirmation like "This is the data you entered please click on confirm button to submit data otherwise click cancel" . can anybody help me here . How we can take all the data entered in main jsp page and disply it on another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form with all the fields you require. Submit that form. set the action to the target jsp. 
In the request object of target jsp you will get all the data you entered.

You can specify the action like this form `id="login-form"` `action="Your` action `jsp url`"

Comment: ok.Can you please tell me can we get the all data at single time or we need to get the value of each label and its field on target jsp page? Beacuse it will be better if we can get the all data entered in the form at one time and it will be read only on target form

Comment: You can use : Enumeration requestParameters = request.getParameterNames();
while (requestParameters.hasMoreElements()) {
    String element = (String) requestParameters.nextElement();
    String value = request.getParameter(element);
}

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

- store the values in the session. Then read it from there on the 2nd page
- send all the values as GET parameters (in case of redirect) or request attributes (in case of page forward)
- use a flash scope (if you are using a framework that supports it)

Comment: thanks for ur help! I am not using any framework . Here i can get all these values by using request attribute.But now i am thinking about new problem. See here situation is i am taking all the order details on jsp page.after user clicks on submit button i am validating thse fields through JS. After validatio i want to show  these details on other jsp page and then again i want to submit these details to servlet(DB) so how can i set two events on submit button on main page? one for calling show details page and other for  submitting details?

Comment: just use request or session attributes to store the values, and redisplay them. Then either submit them again, or just get them from the session